# How to remove na and count values NxK arrays in numpy in a vectorized way

Tags: python, numpy, nan

My situation: i have a pandas dataframe so that, for each row, I have to compute the following.

1) Get the first valute `na` excluded (`df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0])`)

2) Get the last valute `na` excluded (`df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[-1])`)

3) Count the non `na` values (`df.apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna())`)

Sample case and expected output :

```
x = np.array([[1,2,np.nan], [4,5,6], [np.nan, 8,9]])
1) [1, 4, 8]
2) [2, 6, 9]
3) [2, 3, 2]
```

And i need to keep it optimized. So i turned to `numpy` and looked for a way to apply y = `x[~numpy.isnan(x)]` on a `NxK` array as a first step. Then,i would use what was shown here ([Vectorized way of accessing row specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650066/vectorized-way-of-accessing-row-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)) for 1) and 2) but i am still empty handed for 3)

Comment: Add a sample case?

Comment: Added test case

Comment: Edited to row instead of columns, as looking at the sample that's what I gathered. Feel free to edit/rollback if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
In [756]: x
Out[756]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.],
       [ nan,   8.,   9.]])

In [768]: m = ~np.isnan(x)

In [769]: first_idx = m.argmax(1)

In [770]: last_idx = m.shape[1] - m[:,::-1].argmax(1) - 1

In [771]: x[np.arange(len(first_idx)), first_idx]
Out[771]: array([ 1.,  4.,  8.])

In [772]: x[np.arange(len(last_idx)), last_idx]
Out[772]: array([ 2.,  6.,  9.])

In [773]: m.sum(1)
Out[773]: array([2, 3, 2])
```

Alternatively, we could make use of `cumulative-summation` to get those indices, like so -

```
In [787]: c = m.cumsum(1)

In [788]: first_idx = (c==1).argmax(1)

In [789]: last_idx = c.argmax(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are always the best when It comes to these topics